# Trigonometry Integration

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Evaluate:
Integral of

$$\int\frac {\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\log(\cos x)\, dx$$

I've tried to do some werk like canceling the first trig there but all are futile.

Help me out pls.

Comment: Do you have there $\;\ln\cos x\;$ ?

Comment: $$\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}=\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}=\frac{\cos2x}{1+\sin2x}=\frac12\frac{d(1+\sin2x)}{1+\sin 2x}$$

Comment: Please clarify the question and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Incosx dx is multiply to the on yhu wrote sir

Comment: pls avd txtspk.

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator of the fraction part by cosx and get the fraction written by tanx. Then notice that (lncosx)'=-tanx.

Comment: yeah,
that was what I got 
buh the examner said it's wrong

Comment: @Corradi Why wrong? That sounds like a perfectly valid approach!

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an idea. transform $cos(x)$, $sin(x)$ into exponential form.

$cos(x)=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$, $sin(x)=(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2i$. put these in the integrand ,Then separate the real and complex part and do the integration. It will probably be some lengthy calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean,

$$\int \frac{\cos x - \sin x}{\cos x + \sin x} \mathrm dx$$

? Substitute $u = \cos x + \sin x$.

Comment: Incosx dx is multiply to it

Comment: $\ln \cos x$? Can't get Wolfram Alpha to confirm but I am certain there will be no closed form. Maybe some nice results given some limits, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean,

$$\int (\frac{\cos x - \sin x}{\cos x } + \sin x) \ln (\cos x ) \mathrm dx$$

or

$$\int ( \frac{\cos x - \sin x}{\cos x + \sin x}) \ln (\cos x ) \mathrm dx$$

?

Comment: You are lucky your question has not been put "on hold".